# Azure storage REST API response includes BOM (ï»¿” ) at that start of the XML file

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-devops-extensions

I am developing a custom vsts extension for a release task which have a picklist which has values populated from the REST endpoint data source ( my storage account ). I am following this blow link as reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/service-endpoints?view=vsts

I have uploaded my extension but the picklist is not populating with values in the task.

Below are the configurations that I have done.
vss-extension.json:

```
    {
  “manifestVersion”: 1,
  “id”: “build-release-task”,
  “name”: “My Custom release task”,
  “version”: “0.0.1”,
  “publisher”: “custext”,
  “public”: false,
   “targets”: [
  {
    “id”: “Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services”
  }
  ],
  “description”: “A picklist which has values populated from the REST 
   endpoint data source. Includes one build/release task.”,
   “categories”: [
   “Build and release”
  ],
  “icons”: {
  “default”: “images/extension-icon.png”
  },
  “files”: [
 {
 “path”: “buildAndReleaseTask”
    }
   ],
 “contributions”: [
   {
   “id”: “service-endpoint”,
   “description”: “Service Endpoint type for custom Storage connection”,
   “type”: “ms.vss-endpoint.service-endpoint-type”,
    “targets”: [ “ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-types” ],
   “properties”: {
  “name”: “custom”,
  “displayName”: “Custom server connection”,
  “url”: {
   “displayName”: “Server Url”,
   “helpText”: “storage end point url.”
   },
   “dataSources”: [
   {
    “name”: “Storage Account”,
    “endpointUrl”: “{{endpoint.url}}test/?restype=container&comp=list”,
    “resultSelector”: “xpath://EnumerationResults/Blobs/Blob/Name”
     }
    ],

   ]
   }

    ],
   “helpMarkDown”: “Learn More”
   }

   },
    {
    “id”: “custom-build-release-task”,
    “type”: “ms.vss-distributed-task.task”,
    “description”: “Task with a dynamic property getting data from an 
   endpoint REST data source”,
   “targets”: [
   “ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks”
   ],
    “properties”: {
     “name”: “buildAndReleaseTask”
     }
   }
   ]

   }
```

**task.json:**

```
       {
        “id”: “325958a0-63b7-11e6-88a5-f7c7f66e6264”,
        “name”: “dropdownlist”,
        “friendlyName”: “Drop down list”,
        “description”: “Lists the db files”,
        “helpMarkDown”: “Custom release task.Drop down list”,
        “category”: “Utility”,
        “visibility”: [
        “Release”
        ],
      “author”: “satyam”,
      “version”: {
      “Major”: 0,
      “Minor”: 1,
      “Patch”: 0
      },
        “instanceNameFormat”: “dropdownlist $(message)”,
        “groups”: [
          {
           “name”: “advanced”,
           “displayName”: “Advanced”,
           “isExpanded”: false
         }
       ],
        “inputs”: [
           {
             “name”: “CustomService”,
              “type”: “connectedService:custom”,
              “label”: “Storage end point”,
              “defaultValue”: “”,
              “required”: true,
              “helpMarkDown”: “Select the storage account to use. If needed, 
               click on ‘manage’, and add a new Service Endpoint of type 
                 ‘Custom server connection'”
                },
             {
                 “name”: “Scripts”,
                 “type”: “pickList”,
                  “label”: “saasscripts”,
                  “required”: true,
                 “helpMarkDown”: “Select the name of the saas script.”,
                 “properties”: {
                 “EditableOptions”: “True”
                    }
                  }
                 ],
                 “dataSourceBindings”: [
                   {
                    “target”: “Scripts”,
                    “endpointId”: “$(CustomService)”,
                    “dataSourceName”: “Storage Account”
                  }
                  ],
                 “outputVariables”: [
                    {
                      “name”: “dbfile”,
                      “description”: “Application URL of the selected App 
                       Service.”
                     }
                ],
                “execution”: {
                “Node”: {
                   “target”: “powershell.js”
               }
             }
          }
```

endpointUrl: I tried with following ways in endpointUrl in datasources (vss-extension.json)

1. {{endpoint.url}}test/?restype=container&comp=list
   2.https://mycontainername.blob.core.windows.net/test/restype=container&comp=list

The picklist is not populated with the blob contents. 
I guess problem in above issue might be unable to parse the azure storage blob list response type. the rest api response includes BOM (ï»¿” ) at that start of the XML file which might be cause of the parsing.
ï»¿

Is there any way or workaround to change the azure blob rest api response to exclude BOM (ï»¿” ) or changing the response to JSON format.

Comment: I'm getting this too, did you ever find a reason why this happened or a way to force it send valid xml back?